# Adding sherlock action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to implement action bar in my android application. I have searched for that and I found out the I need to add some libraries in order to able to use action bar for android 2.X. I started following some online tutorials about adding sherlock actionbar. In every tutorial its mentioned that when I extract the library file which I downloaded from :[here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html)

I should get three folders samples, library, and website. But I didn't get them.

So I couldn't follow the rest of the tutorial. Here is the list of the files and folders I have got after extracting the folder :

```
actionbarsherlock          build.gradle     deploy_website.sh  RELEASING.md
actionbarsherlock-fest     CHANGELOG.md     LICENSE.txt        settings.gradle
actionbarsherlock-i18n     checkstyle.xml   pom.xml            website
actionbarsherlock-samples  CONTRIBUTING.md  README.md
```

I'm using Linux mint and eclipse. Can anyone tell me how to add the sherlock library?

Comment: you can use android action bar comparability library instead. You can add action bar on 2.x using this library.

Comment: Can you please give me a link with instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use actionbarsherlock ? Support for the action bar is added now in support library.
"From your activity, you can retrieve an instance of ActionBar by calling getSupportActionBar()."

see the link below for more info.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Comment: Is it supported for android 2.x ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use use [ActionBar Compat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html)?
It's available in the support library v7, allows minSdk 7 and it's a library from Google.

Furthermore the development of ActionBarSherlock is stopped

Answer (score 1):

1.First you need to import sherlock lib project to eclipse.
2.Now add this library project to your sample project(Right click on project ->Properties--->Android-->add library)
NOTE: your sample project path and library project path shall be same.

3.Now create a Sherlock Activity instead of simple activity by extending SherlockActivity class .
4.You also need to change theme also.

Comment: As I said when I extracted the folder there wasn't a "library" folder in it

Comment: actionbarsherlock-i18n is the library project

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu is a good example for Sherlock download as zip and import it to you workspace i hope it help you